# How to isolate grid lines on top of a curve Mathematica

Tags: grid, wolfram-mathematica, gridlines

I am looking to plot a graph which has a semi circle from -3 to 3 on the x axis and 0 to 3 on the y axis. I would like for the semi circle and its interior to be untouched but the rest of the graph be filled with grid lines (with a point with increments of .06 for x and y values). I have been able to plot a graph with the semi circle and the grid lines but can't seem to figure out how to clear the semi circle of grid lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have so far, with f[x] being the function for the semicircle and the xPoints and yPoints being the x and y coordinates.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}, 
 GridLines -> {{xPoints},{yPoints}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

try working with `RegionPlot`

```
 RegionPlot[ x^2+y^2 < 9 , {x,-3,3 }, {y,0,3} , Mesh->10 , AspectRatio->Automatic,
               MeshShading->{{None,None},{None,None}} ]
```

[image]

( Just switch the inequality to get the grid outside the curve )